# What is 'the regular expression library supplied by [my] system'?

Tags: regex, linux, gnu

The *man* page for GNU's *less* utility says the following about searching:

```
/pattern
    Search forward in the file for the N-th line containing the pattern.  N
    defaults to 1.  The pattern is a regular expression, as recognized by the
    regular expression library supplied by your system.
```

I use *less* on all sorts of systems: my personal Ubuntu laptop, my CentOS cloud server, under Cygwin at work, etc. I keep wanting to do things like negative look-aheads and other fancy stuff, but I don't know what regex syntax to use. How do I find out?

Comment: Not a full answer, but I'd start here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_regular_expression_engines

Comment: Thanks. Any advice on how to map the libraries in @hek2mgl's answer to this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It is a compile time parameter. The ./configure script of less knows the `with-regex=LIB` param.

This is a quote from README of the upstream package:

> --with-regex=lib

```
     Specifies the regular expression library used by less for pattern
     matching.  The default is "auto", which means the configure program 
     finds a regular expression library automatically.  Other values are:
        posix          Use the POSIX-compatible regcomp.
        pcre           Use the PCRE library.
        regcmp         Use the regcmp library.
        re_comp        Use the re_comp library.
        regcomp        Use the V8-compatible regcomp.
        regcomp-local  Use Henry Spencer's V8-compatible regcomp
                       (source is supplied with less).
```

So you would need to know how less was './configured'. I have investigated this on Debian / Ubuntu. They use the POSIX regex lib.

I'm still searching for a way to detect it dynamically by a script... :)

---

Update: The only thing I've managed so far was to detect whether less uses pcre regexes or not. If less was configured using `--with-regex=pcre` it is linked against the libpcre.so shared library:

```
#!/bin/bash

# ldd prints out the shared libraries a binary is linked to.
# This can be used to check if less is linked against libpcre
if ldd "$(which less)" | grep 'libpcre\.so' ; then   
    echo "less uses pcre regex syntax"
else 
    echo "less uses non pcre regex syntax"
    # ... more checks should follow. currently trying to find a way
fi
```

Comment: Thanks. At least I know now where to look, but I'm sure further updates from you would be helpful.

From some quick web searches, it looks like pcre is the only one with the kind of advanced features I want—would you agree?

Comment: if you prefer them, ok. (me too:)) I'm currently thinking about hashing the `less` binary, compiled with several `--with-regex` options, and then just compare the hashes to say which regex lib is used (at a certain system). But if you are happy with my answer, I'll be too! :)

Comment: I'm *satisfied* with your answer, since it answers my question. Such a hash would make me *happier*, though. ;-) Let me know if there's anything I can do to either help, or incentivise you. I'll keep an eye on the email address in my StackExchange profile for now.

Comment: @MichaelScheper The email address isn't displayed. (seems private) If you wan't you can contact me via the email displayed on my homepage. You'll find it when looking at my profile on SO

Comment: I learnt the provenance of some of these libraries in an [appendix](https://www.gnu.org/software/gcal/manual/html_node/Regular-Expressions.html) of the manual for [GNU gcal](https://www.gnu.org/software/gcal/). Could you add descriptions to your answer?

Comment: Have you checked the output of `ldd /usr/bin/gcal` ?

Comment: @hek2mgl Yes, though on my immediate system (Solaris 10) `ldd gcal` (and `ldd less`) only elicits a link to _libc_ (and other non-regex-specific libraries). `elfdump less` produced something positive, perhaps I'll add an answer of my own. Earlier, I meant that I was interested to learn that `regcmp` (also mentioned above in README of `less` pkg) comes from SysV (AT&T?) and `re_comp` comes from BSD. Previously, I haven't paid much attention to lineages of regex engines.

Comment: @crw Yeah, you should consider posting an answer. Would like to see how you used `elfdump`.

Answer (score 7):

I don't know if this works in all cases (older versions/different systems) but I was able to find this info using `less --version`:

```
less 458 (GNU regular expressions)
Copyright (C) 1984-2012 Mark Nudelman

less comes with NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
For information about the terms of redistribution,
see the file named README in the less distribution.
Homepage: http://www.greenwoodsoftware.com/less
```

So it's GNU regex syntax...

And after compiling a newer version with `--with-regex=pcre` I got

```
less 481 (PCRE regular expressions)
...
```

**Update**

Thanks to [crw](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1184892/crw) for checking. *This solution does appear to be version-specific*. After compiling available source code at [greenwoodsoftware](http://www.greenwoodsoftware.com/less/download.html) (in Linux), I found that it *does not* work for versions 436 (released 25 Jul 2009) and earlier. It starts working by at least 451 (released 4 Sep 2012) and later. (Versions in between these were not available for download).

Comment: Wow, right under our noses. If there's a way to verify that this is always the case, I'd mark this the 'accepted' answer.

Comment: Unfortunately, I found the world to be more complex than I'd believed... See update above.

Answer (score 0):

The suggested answer to observe the output of `less --version` didn't address my situation on Solaris 10 -- the first two lines read:

```
less 436
Copyright (C) 1984-2009 Mark Nudelman
```

I cannot see an obvious regex library in the list of dynamic dependencies:

```
$ ldd /usr/bin/less
        libcurses.so.1 =>        /lib/libcurses.so.1
        libc.so.1 =>     /lib/libc.so.1
        libm.so.2 =>     /lib/libm.so.2
        /lib/libm/libm_hwcap1.so.2
        /platform/sun4v/lib/libc_psr.so.1
```

`man libc` indicates that multiple regex interfaces are offered by the library: `regcmp`, `re_comp` and `regcomp`.

By running `elfdump` against the binary, I can see references to the symbol `regcomp`:

```
$ elfdump /usr/bin/less | egrep -i 'posix|pcre|regcmp|re_comp|regcomp|regcomp-local'
     [452]  0x0003d6a0 0x00000000  FUNC GLOB  D    0 UNDEF          regcomp
            [452]       regcomp
  R_SPARC_JMP_SLOT            0x3d6a0          0  .rela.plt      regcomp
```

If this is a link to the `regcomp` regex compiler function, then the README-text in the answer from @hek2mgl suggests that this `less` binary might use POSIX regexes (or Spencer V8 regexes, if compiled into the binary?).

The man page for `regcomp(3C)` reads:

```
DESCRIPTION
     These functions interpret basic and extended regular expres-
     sions (described on the regex(5) manual page).
```

Experimenting with searches in `less`, I've discovered that the regex repetition operator `{...}` works without backslash escapes. The manpage for `regex(5)` on my system defines this as Extended Regular Expression (ERE) syntax.

Lastly, I've found [several](https://www.gnu.org/software/gcal/manual/html_node/Regular-Expressions.html) interesting [descriptions](http://unixpapa.com/incnote/regex.html) of the interfaces of various regex engines, summarised below:

```
Engine            Interface
----------------  --------------------------------
GNU               re_compile_pattern() and regex.h
PCRE              pcre_compile and pcre.h / pcre2_compile and pcre2.h
POSIX             regcomp() and regex.h
Henry Spencer V8  regcomp() and regexp.h
BSD               re_comp()
System V          regcmp()
```